# connect spring boot app to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

i'm trying to connect my spring boot app to a remote mongodb database.
When i run my app i got this error:

2017-05-25 15:22:57.829  INFO 4532 --- [*******:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server **mongodb-server-address:27017**

com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:63) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:115) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:113) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: **Connection refused: connect**

Answer (score 2):

By default MongoDB only binds to the loopback interface which makes it only accessible from localhost. To change that you need to edit this line in `mongod.conf` file;

you can change it to allow LAN and local connections or you can remove or comment out that line `bind_ip = 127.0.0.1` to allow all connections.

For more info : [MongoDB – Allow remote access](http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/mongodb-allow-remote-access/)